# How do I link a button to another page in Jsbin without posting my website to the internet?

Tags: html, css, jsbin

I'm trying to build a website using html and css in jsbin. When I try to  link a button (using the outlined code: `<a href="generated name given by JSbin">Home</b>`) I enter the page name generated by jsbin (on the left hand side of each page in the bin) within the quotation marks, but for some reason it only works sometimes. I don't want to post my website to the internet, but I want to link my pages together within my jsbin account. Is there anyway I can do this?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<button class="Homebtn"><a href="xerimi">Home</a></button>
```

Any help is great! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to build your website in JSBin?

Comment: Do you suggest a better site? I just found it easy to use.

Comment: JSBin is intended to be a prototyping tool, not a website hosting or creation tool. There's a lot of options specially created for your needs, just research a little bit more.

Comment: For my circumstances JSBin seems quite sufficient, especially for sharing purposes. Prototyping/testing with JSBin is just what I have been doing and now it seems difficult to interweave my bins into a full, coherent format. That's why I asked if there is a way to link my buttons as it has only worked some of the time.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand JSBin isn't really an IDE. Think of it more as a way to test out HTML/CSS/Javascript ideas. So I think you're asking it to do more than it's made to do.

For a full web development environment try something like [codeanywhere](https://codeanywhere.com/).

I'm sure there are lots more web-based development environments too.

Or you can put a text editor on your computer and start writing code in it and running it locally before you put it online. I use [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/).

I know this isn't really what you're wanting to hear, but it should be pretty easy to copy and paste what you have so far into another environment and linking pages should be easy.

Comment: Sweet! I really appreciate your help. I am new to coding and I suppose I also have little experience as to what softwares will work for me, my code, and my computer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. On stackoverflow, you can show your appreciation by accepting the answer as solving your problem and/or giving it an up arrow. It gives the answerer (me in this case) reputation points.